# Python using scipy.optimise to find the solution to an equation

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I want to solve an equation using `scipy.optimise`

I want to find the solution, n, for the equation

```
a**n + b**n = c**n
```

where

```
a=2.3
b=2.4
c=2.94
```

I have a list of triplets (a,b,c) I want to experiment with and I know the range of the exponent n will always be 2.0 < n < 4.0. Could I use this fact to speed up the convergence of the solution.

Comment: FWIW, the solution is ~ 3.101065595759040974. I used [mpmath](http://mpmath.org/) to find the solution; its [`findroot`](http://mpmath.org/doc/current/calculus/optimization.html#mpmath.findroot) function accepts a starting-point arg which may be an interval.

Comment: @PM2Ring Thanks but I'm looking for a python solution to that problem as I have a long list of triplets to work with.

Comment: Ah, ok. Sorry, I don't know scipy. But you may find mpmath interesting, especially if you want high precision.

Comment: @PM2Ring Actually I'm interested in how you used mpmath. Can you post your code as a solution on this page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your function is scalar, and accepts a scalar (your case), and if you know that:

- your solution is in a given interval, and the function is continuous in the same interval (your case)
- you are interested in one solution, not necessarily in all (if more than 1) solutions in that interval

You can speed up the solution using the [bisection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method) algorithm, implemented [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.bisect.html) in scipy, which requires the conditions above to guarantee convergence. 
The idea behind the algorithm is quite simple, with log convergence.

See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem) fundamental calculus theorem on which the algorithm is based.

EDIT: I couldn't resist, here you have a MWE

```
import scipy.optimize as opt
def sol(a,b,c):
    f  = lambda n : a**n + b**n - c**n
    return opt.bisect(f,2,4)
print(sol(2.3,2.4,2.94)

>3.1010655957
```

Answer (score 1):

As requested in the comments, here's how to do it using [mpmath](http://mpmath.org).

We supply the `a`, `b`, `c` parameters as strings rather than as Python floats for maximum accuracy. Converting strings to `mpf` (`mp` floats) will be as accurate as the current precision allows. If instead we convert from Python floats then we'd be using numbers that suffer from the imprecision inherent in Python floats.

`mp.dps` allows us to set the precision in the form of the number of decimal digits.

The mpmath [`findroot`](http://mpmath.org/doc/current/calculus/optimization.html#mpmath.findroot) function accepts an initial approximation argument. This can be a single value, or it may be an interval, given as a list or a tuple. It's ok to use Python floats in that interval.

```
from mpmath import mp

mp.dps = 30

a, b, c = [mp.mpf(u) for u in ('2.3', '2.4', '2.94')]

def f(x):
    return a**x + b**x - c**x

x = mp.findroot(f, [2, 4])

print(x, f(x))
```

**output**

```
3.10106559575904097402104750305 -3.15544362088404722164691426113e-30
```

By default, `findroot` uses a simple secant solver. The docs recommend using the 'anderson' or 'ridder' solvers when supplying an interval, but for this equation all 3 solvers give identical results.